# Web after JS load dont scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a web http://xn--uasencarnadas-ikb.es/ and i noticed that when JS is loaded scroll doesn't work

Any ideas?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: I can't replicate that behavior. I'm able to scroll just fine.

Comment: It's happening in chrome. In Firefox works ok :S

Comment: I tried in Chrome, it scrolls fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, thanks, seems to be an issue with my chrome :S I tried on another machine and its true, seems to work